# Как сделать три блока одинаковой высоты в CSS с отступами?

Tags: css

[image: Пример]Как создать три резиновых блока одинаковой высоты, чтобы контур был как на картинке? Испробовал различные варианты, не получается найти решение. С таблицей почему-то не получается добиться одинакового контура по высоте. Изначально пробовал этот html, потом пробовал добавлять обертки:
С кругами сложности нет, только с обводкой на резиновых блоках.

```css
.blocks-promo {
    position: relative; 
 width: 100%;
 margin: 40px 0;
}
.block-promo-wrapper {
 position: relative;
 width: 33.3333%;
 float: left;
 padding: 50px 10px 0;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.block-promo-icon-assortiment,
.block-promo-icon-otnosheniia,
.block-promo-icon-opyt {
 position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-color: #95c12b;
}
.block-promo-icon-assortiment:before,
.block-promo-icon-otnosheniia:before,
.block-promo-icon-opyt:before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 height: 48px;
 width: 48px;
 top: 26px;
 left: 26px;
}
.block-promo-icon-assortiment:before {
 background: url('../images/ic_shopping_cart_white_48px.svg') no-repeat;
}
.block-promo-icon-otnosheniia:before {
 background: url('../images/ic_group_white_48px.svg') no-repeat;
}
.block-promo-icon-opyt:before {
 background: url('../images/ic_star_white_48px.svg') no-repeat;
}
.block-promo-content {
 padding: 80px 20px 30px;
 border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
.block-promo-title {
    text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 770px) {
 .block-promo-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks-promo">
 <div class="block-promo-wrapper">
  <span class="block-promo-icon-assortiment"></span>
  <div class="block-promo-content">
   <h2 class="block-promo-title">Заголовок</h2>
   <p>Текст  текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="block-promo-wrapper">
  <span class="block-promo-icon-otnosheniia"></span>
  <div class="block-promo-content">
   <h2 class="block-promo-title">Заголовок</h2>
   <p>Текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="block-promo-wrapper">
  <span class="block-promo-icon-opyt"></span>
  <div class="block-promo-content">
   <h2 class="block-promo-title">Заголовок</h2>
   <p>Текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь! Все ответы рабочие, выбрал table поскольку поддерживается большим количеством браузеров.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с использованием `display: table`

Для отступов используем [border-spacing](http://htmlbook.ru/css/border-spacing)

Таблицу делим на колонки равной ширины с помощью `table-layout: fixed`

> Ширина колонок в этом случае определяется либо с помощью тега `<col>`, либо вычисляется на основе первой строки. Если данные о форматировании первой строки таблицы по каким-либо причинам получить невозможно, в этом случае таблица делится на колонки равной ширины. При использовании этого значения, содержимое, которое не помещается в ячейку указанной ширины, будет «обрезано» либо наложено поверх ячейки. Это зависит от используемого браузера, но в любом случае ширина ячейки меняться не будет. Для корректной работы этого значения обязательно должна быть задана ширина таблицы.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.b {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  border-spacing: 10px 65px;
}
.b-item {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
.b-item-circle {
  margin: -65px auto 10px auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.b-item-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="b">
  <div class="b-item">
    <div class="b-item-circle"></div>
    <div class="b-item-title">title</div>
    <div class="b-item-text">text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="b-item">
    <div class="b-item-circle"></div>
    <div class="b-item-title">title</div>
    <div class="b-item-text">Как создать три резиновых блока одинаковой высоты, чтобы контур был как на картинке? Испробовал различные варианты, не получается найти решение. С таблицей почему-то не получается добиться одинакового контура по высоте. Изначально пробовал этот html,
      потом пробовал добавлять обертки: С кругами сложности нет, только с обводкой на резиновых блоках.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="b-item">
    <div class="b-item-circle"></div>
    <div class="b-item-title">title</div>
    <div class="b-item-text">text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю, но table-layout: fixed; фиксирует ширину, а блоки должны быть резиновыми.

Comment: table-layout: fixed; - таблица делится на колонки равной ширины

Comment: Мне кажется height: 50px; в классе .b лишнее.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема была с `padding'ом`, сейчас все работает.
Когда вы в блок добавляете `padding`, это всегда за счет ширины, и тогда блок не встает на свое место.

```css
.blocks-promo {
  position: relative;
  display:flex;
  align-items:stretch;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 40px 0;
}
.block-promo-wrapper {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  padding-right:50px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.block-promo-icon-assortiment,
.block-promo-icon-otnosheniia,
.block-promo-icon-opyt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: #95c12b;
}
.block-promo-icon-assortiment:before,
.block-promo-icon-otnosheniia:before,
.block-promo-icon-opyt:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  top: 26px;
  left: 26px;
}
.block-promo-icon-assortiment:before {
  background: url('../images/ic_shopping_cart_white_48px.svg') no-repeat;
}
.block-promo-icon-otnosheniia:before {
  background: url('../images/ic_group_white_48px.svg') no-repeat;
}
.block-promo-icon-opyt:before {
  background: url('../images/ic_star_white_48px.svg') no-repeat;
}
.block-promo-content {
  padding: 80px 20px 30px;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  height: calc(100% - 110px)
}
.block-promo-title {
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 770px) {
.block-promo-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
.blocks-promo {
  position: relative;
  display:block;
  align-items:stretch;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks-promo">
 <div class="block-promo-wrapper">
  <span class="block-promo-icon-assortiment"></span>
  <div class="block-promo-content">
   <h2 class="block-promo-title">Заголовок</h2>
   <p>Текст  текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="block-promo-wrapper">
  <span class="block-promo-icon-otnosheniia"></span>
  <div class="block-promo-content">
   <h2 class="block-promo-title">Заголовок</h2>
   <p>Текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="block-promo-wrapper">
  <span class="block-promo-icon-opyt"></span>
  <div class="block-promo-content">
   <h2 class="block-promo-title">Заголовок</h2>
   <p>Текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю, но у вас как раз таки получился один из моих вариантов, где в итоге нет отступов, как на картинке, а результат нужен как на картинке.

Comment: Проверьте сейчас, все работает

Comment: @L.Vadim, пожалуйста, выравнивай свой код в ответах

Comment: ok, сейчас выровнию

Answer (score 2):

Могу предложить реализацию этой проблемы с помощью flexbox. Так блоки выйдут более гибкими. Так же я установлю фиксированную высоту для `.text`, что бы вы увидели, что высота родительского блока остаётся одинаковой (можно фиксированную высоту убрать):

```css
body {font-family: arial;}

.blocks {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
.blocks .block {
    position: relative;
    padding: 35px 8px 8px 8px;
    margin: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #efefef;
    flex: 1;
}
.blocks .block .circle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #95c12c;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.blocks .block .title {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    padding: 4px;
    font-size: 0.8rem
}
.blocks .block .text {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 4px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="title">Заголовок</div>
    <div class="text" style="height: 80px;">Текст</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="title">Заголовок</div>
    <div class="text" style="height: 60px;">Текст</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="title">Заголовок</div>
    <div class="text" style="height: 70px;">Текст</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю, но тут проблема в том, что нет отступов между блоками. Чего я и не смог добиться в таблицах.

Comment: @SergeyEremin, редактировал ответ. Отступ легко создаётся

Comment: Ширину смотрю фиксированную поставили, вариант с 33.333% не подходит?

Comment: @SergeyEremin, держите, блоки без фиксированной ширины, подстраиваются под всю ширину

Comment: @SergeyEremin Отступ можете задать либо фиксированный `.block + .block { /* любое число px */ margin-left: 10px; }` либо резиновый, задавая для `.blocks { justify-content: space-between; }` для `.block { /* любое число % */ width: 20% }`, удалите `flex: 1;` и всё.

Comment: @SergeyEremin Можете также для `.blocks { justify:content:space-around; }` задать вместо `space-between`. Тоже интересный эффект.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен [Flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```
.blocks-promo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

Вложенный элемент посчитайте от 100% высоты - отсутпы:

```
.block-promo-content {
  height: calc(100% - 110px)
}
```

```css
.blocks-promo {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 40px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.block-promo-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  padding: 50px 10px 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.block-promo-icon-assortiment,
.block-promo-icon-otnosheniia,
.block-promo-icon-opyt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: #95c12b;
}
.block-promo-icon-assortiment:before,
.block-promo-icon-otnosheniia:before,
.block-promo-icon-opyt:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  top: 26px;
  left: 26px;
}
.block-promo-icon-assortiment:before {
  background: url('../images/ic_shopping_cart_white_48px.svg') no-repeat;
}
.block-promo-icon-otnosheniia:before {
  background: url('../images/ic_group_white_48px.svg') no-repeat;
}
.block-promo-icon-opyt:before {
  background: url('../images/ic_star_white_48px.svg') no-repeat;
}
.block-promo-content {
  padding: 80px 20px 30px;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  height: calc(100% - 110px)
}
.block-promo-title {
  text-align: center;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 770px) {
  .block-promo-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks-promo">
  <div class="block-promo-wrapper">
    <span class="block-promo-icon-assortiment"></span>
    <div class="block-promo-content">
      <h2 class="block-promo-title">Заголовок</h2>
      <p>Текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block-promo-wrapper">
    <span class="block-promo-icon-otnosheniia"></span>
    <div class="block-promo-content">
      <h2 class="block-promo-title">Заголовок</h2>
      <p>Текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block-promo-wrapper">
    <span class="block-promo-icon-opyt"></span>
    <div class="block-promo-content">
      <h2 class="block-promo-title">Заголовок</h2>
      <p>Текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Насчёт height: calc(100% - 110px) не понял для чего это делается. Я так понял судя потому что родительский блок смещается, это нужно для просчета, чтобы вложенный блок вернуть на место.

Comment: С помощью `align-items: stretch;` родительские блоки выравниваются по высоте. Но вложенные в них блоки остаются своей высоты, поэтому я ставлю `100% height` и отнимаю `110px` - сумма `padding` сверху и снизу. Можно как вариант заменить на `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение! Единственно принял с таблицами потому как у них больше поддержки разных браузеров.